# Adding category data to URLs in Low Search results

Tags: categories, low-search

I would to add category in the Low Search Url result.

On my page result appears the Channel name and the entry name:

```
www.mysite/recipes/hamburger
```

But i would insert the categories:

```
www.mysite/recipes/meat/beef/hamburger
```

I'm using this:

```
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_2}"}
      <a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}">{title}</a>
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

I tried but without success
Thanks,

Stéphane

Comment: Which part of the URL are you trying to use for the search? The channel, the category, or the entry?

Comment: it`s the category i would insert before the entry. i didn`t remenber the {categories}/{category_url_title}{/categories}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to construct it yourself, most likely with the native `{categories}` var pair. Something like this:

```
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_2}"}
    <a href="/recipes{categories}/{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}">
        {title}
    </a>
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

However, you can imagine how that turns out if your entry has a *lot* of categories. Also, I'm not sure if the `{categories}` var pair respects the order of the categories, based on parent/child relationship. It might be necessary to look for an add-on that gives you more control over the output of the entry's categories.

Comment: Thanks a lot Low,  I ever used it but I was confused with many EE syntax. Now it`s more clear!!!!

Comment: We use GWcode Categories for outputting an entries categories. Much easier to control child / parent categories etc